# “ warnings.warn('the tensorboard callback does not support '”

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

“  warnings.warn('the tensorboard callback does not support '”
when i wanted to use the Tensorboard ,i meet such promblem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqOYh.png)

Comment: Its best to copy code into question as *text*, rather than an image. Then it is possible for people to copy it, for execution, or to search for related documents/examples/discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list the callback in `model.fit` call.

Try:

```
tb_callback = Tensorboard(...)
model.fit(..., callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

I didn't like naming the callback `Tensorboard`, so I changed it to `tb_callback`. Then I told `model.fit` to use that callback.